# How do I iterate through lines in an external file with shell?

Tags: bash, shell

I have one file with a list of names.  I need to loop through all names in this file from an external file with a shell script.  How can I do that?

Example files:

scripts/names.txt

```
alison
barb
charlie
david
```

scripts/script.sh

```
NAMES="" #names from names.txt file
for NAME in $NAMES; do
    echo "$NAME"
done
```

How can I explode the names.txt file into an array in a separate shell script?

Comment: How about a link to the original Q&A?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

One way would be:

```
while read NAME
do
    echo "$NAME"
done < names.txt
```

**EDIT:**
<strike>Note that the loop gets executed in a sub-shell, so any modified variables will be local, except if you declare them with `declare` outside the loop.</strike>

Dennis Williamson is right. Sorry, must have used piped constructs too often and got confused.

Comment: No, since nothing is being piped into `while`, there's no subshell. Redirection into `done` doesn't create a subshell.

Comment: By the way, the issue (bug?) with pipes does not occur with korn shell (but does with pdksh).

Comment: Someone should clarify that the file you're looping over should have an empty last line, otherwise the last element won't be considered

Answer (score 15):

You'll be wanting to use the 'read' command

```
while read name
do
    echo "$name"
done < names.txt
```

Note that "$name" is quoted -- if it's not, it will be split using the characters in `$IFS` as delimiters. This probably won't be noticed if you're just echoing the variable, but if your file contains a list of file names which you want to copy, those will get broken down by `$IFS` if the variable is unquoted, which is not what you want or expect.

If you want to use Mike Clark's approach (loading into a variable rather than using read), you can do it without the use of `cat`:

```
NAMES="$(< scripts/names.txt)" #names from names.txt file
for NAME in $NAMES; do
    echo "$NAME"
done
```

The problem with this is that it loads the whole file into `$NAMES`, when you read it back out, you can either get the whole file (if quoted) or the file broken down by `$IFS`, if not quoted. By default, this will give you individual words, not individual lines. So if the name "Mary Jane" appeared on a line, you would get "Mary" and "Jane" as two separate names. Using `read` will get around this... although you could also change the value of `$IFS`

Answer (score 9):

```
cat names.txt|while read line; do
    echo "$line";
done
```

Comment: `while read line; do ...; done < names.txt`

Answer (score 5):

I know the purists will hate this method, but you can `cat` the file.

```
NAMES=`cat scripts/names.txt` #names from names.txt file
for NAME in $NAMES; do
   echo "$NAME"
done
```

Comment: This has the advantage of not invoking a sub-shell, but will consider any space in `names.txt` as a delimiter.

Comment: The "purists" will helpfully explain what's wrong with this, too.  There are multiple issues.  See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
cat <<\! >names.txt
> alison
> barb
> charlie
> david
> !
OIFS=$IFS; IFS=$'\n'; NAMES=($(<names.txt)); IFS=$OIFS
echo "${NAMES[@]}"
alison barb charlie david
echo "${NAMES[0]}"
alison
for NAME in "${NAMES[@]}";do echo $NAME;done
alison
barb
charlie
david
```